# Canvas lineTo is somehow disconnected in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw some simple shapes in a very large canvas, but found a weird situation where the lines were somehow disconnected. Both ends of lines  should meet on far right side of the canvas.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="30500" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" />

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 100);
ctx.lineTo(30200, 200);
ctx.lineTo(20, 300);
ctx.stroke();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It worked perfectly in Chrome, but not in IE11.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: IIRC max width in IE is 8k (ref 30200)

Comment: Just curious, why do you need a canvas that is > 30000 in width?

Comment: @K3N My user was looking for a possibility to draw a very long graphic.

Comment: Btw, I slightly modified the code from 'ctx.lineTo(30200, 200);' to 'ctx.lineTo(16000, 200);' and it's worked. But when I increased to, say 17000, it broke.